# Number of files in a directory starting with specific text

Tags: files, ls, wildcards

How to get count of files in a directory starting with specific text like `dataxxx.csv`

Comment: What is "a directory start"? Do you want to search in a directory named "start". Do you want to search for file with names starting with "dataxxx.csv" (e.g. `dataxxx.csv.123.jpeg`)? Or does the text have to **in** the file? At the start of the files you want to count? Please rewrite you question so it is less ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

There are probably fancier ways, but what works for me is

```
ls /directory/data* | wc -l
```

Comment: foo=$(ls /directory/data* | wc -l)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `data*.csv`? And in your comment, there ought to be double-quotes around the `$()`. Of course, this strategy will not give a correct count if there are files that match the pattern which happen to have a newline char in their name. :)

Comment: Yes, of course it can be data*.csv as well :) I haven't quoted $() when I do this kind of thing and haven't noticed anything breaking. I assume something could - what? And you're of course right about about the names. In any case there are now better answers for the OP than mine :)

Comment: The naked `$()` is ok here, but it's a good habit to double quote stuff: From BashGuide `As with all substitutions, the results of a command substitution will undergo WordSplitting, unless the whole thing is inside double quotes.` So as a rule, quote stuff unless you explicitly want to invoke word splitting.

Answer (score 2):

Using `find` to test that they are a file (`-type f`) and match the required pattern (`"data*.csv"`):

```
find directory/ -type f -name "data*.csv" | wc -l
```

Comment: jasonwryan, your code find the files in subdirectory also but how can i find files only in current directory?

Comment: @user188979 you would use `find . -maxdepth 1 ...` to restrict the search to just the current directory.